# yandex direct api запрос баланса. Ошибка 515

Tags: яндекс-директ

Знакомлюсь с api, в частности с яндекс директом.

в ответе на запрос созданный с помощью сервиса postman
присутствует строка

```
    {
        "FaultDetail": "",
        "FaultCode": 515,
        "FaultString": "Shared account must be connected."
    }
```

Описание данной 515 ошибки отсутствует в справке.
Что означает что аккаунт должен быть подключен? к чему? Аккаунт действующий ис положительным балансом.
По faultcode гуглится какая то автодичь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Такая же проблема на аккаунте полученном от getuniq. Пока не нашел решения. Есть подозрение, что нужно отдельно права в getuniq запрашивать на получение баланса.

Answer (score 0):

https://yandex.ru/dev/direct/doc/dg-v4/reference/ErrorCodes.html

"Попытка получить информацию об общем счете для рекламодателя, у которого общий счет не подключен"

Answer (score 0):

Для корректного получения баланса на аккаунте, выданном агентством, нужно:

1. Передавать токе в теле запроса "token" => "$token", (и в заголовке)
2. В параметрах запроса (зaram) не использовать SelectionCriteria (удалить совсем)
   Запрос будет выглядеть:

   $url = "https://api.direct.yandex.ru/live/v4/json/";
   $headers = array(
   "Authorization: Bearer " . $token,
   "Client-Login: " . $login,
   "Accept-Language: ru",
   "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"
   );
   $data = array(
   "method" => "AccountManagement",
   "param" => array(
   "Action" => "Get",
   ),
   "token" => "$token",
   );

Для обычного аккаунта Яндекс Директ прямого рекламодателя (лично зарегистрированного) можно использовать SelectionCriteria в param.

Данное решение проверено лично и работает на 18.02.2024 года